# Leaving country soon, can I leave my bank accounts open?

Tags: residency, banking, turkey, tunisian-citizens

I am a Tunisian citizen currently residing in Turkey with a work permit. However, due to a restructuring in the startup I worked for, I've been laid off and my work permit will not be renewed. As it's expiring in a few days, I need to return to Tunisia urgently.

I have several bank accounts in Turkey, denominated in TRY, USD, and EUR. I prefer to keep these accounts open and the funds accessible for a few reasons:

The [Tunisian Dinar (TND) is a closed currency](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Tunisian_dinar). While I can easily transfer money into Tunisia, getting it out is a significant challenge.
I'm planning to apply for job opportunities in the EU/UK, so having accessible funds outside Tunisia will be immensely advantageous.

My question is: **Are there any commonly known restrictions or implications for keeping Turkish bank accounts open after losing one's residence status?**

Any advice or personal experiences related to this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do the terms & conditions of the account(s) say about residency requirements?

Comment: FWIW, I have open bank accounts in several countries I used to live and simply never closed. Within Europe nobody really cares, while in other countries I try to interact with the bank as little as possible and only do limited online transactions, so as not to tip them off as to my whereabouts. Not sure if it really matters, but better safe then sorry. Having said that, I don't know about Turkey in particular at all.